# Getting empty value except the first array after pushing 1D to 2D array javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

hi I'm attempting to convert a 1d array to 2d array for google app script in order to paste the same value for the whole column "M".

I have initiated an array PFcheck with the value and another empty array.
Then I attempted to loop through the column's length and add the array to the empty array. 
Not sure why when I push the same array , I'm getting empty array after the first one..

```
function setPFneededDaily(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Tracker2");
  var PFcheck=["PFcheckeeded"],PFcheckarr=[]

  var m=sheet.getRange("M2:M").getValues()
  for(var i=0;i<m.length;i++){
    PFcheckarr.push(PFcheck)
  }
  sheet.getRange("M2:M").setValues(PFcheckarr)
}
```

I attempted the code below but i'm getting 
[["PFcheckneeded"],[],[],[]...]
I'm expecting 
[["PFcheckneeded"],["PFcheckneeded"],["PFcheckneeded"],["PFcheckneeded"]...]

Comment: Can you post an example of input array and expected output array?

Comment: I think that when you run the script in your question, ``PFcheckarr`` has ``[["PFcheckneeded"],["PFcheckneeded"],["PFcheckneeded"],["PFcheckneeded"]...]`` at the line of ``sheet.getRange("M2:M").setValues(PFcheckarr)``.

Answer (score 0):

Initially, is your M column already filled to your desired length, or is just the M2 cell filled? If so, your i loop will only loop once and stop adding `PFCheck` for the rest of the size.